# ThinkPad T460p/T470 screens and webcam - contemplating surgery, seeking advice

Tags: thinkpad, webcam

I have in my possession:

- A ThinkPad T460p with a bad motherboard but a presumably functioning screen
  and webcam, and
- A ThinkPad T470 which works wonderfully but which came with no webcam.

I'm looking to get the T460p webcam working on the T470. I *think* that the approach would be to swap the bezels and move the webcam over. Would that work?

I'm considering swapping screens too. Would the screen hardware indicate resolution on the outside so I could choose the nicer one?

I even thought to swap entire screen assemblies, although looking at the brackets I don't think that would work.

Whichever screen is left over will be part of my next smart mirror project, but that's for another post.

I'm grateful for your thoughts.

Comment: Not doable. Bezels are different and you'd need a connector for the camera, typically an internal USB bus.

Comment: Thank you for saving me from the attempt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible to do per ChanganAuto.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).